# Makefile undefined reference to my namespace objects/functions/constructors

Tags: c++, makefile, namespaces

My code compiles well in codeblocks, but my makefile can't compile because of undefined reference to items with my namespace Chess
how should i specify the namespace in makefile or fix it?

here's the errors example:

```
King.cpp:35: undefined reference to `Chess::Board::getPiece(Chess::Position const&) const'
```

here's my makefile

```
CXXFLAGS = -ISFML-2.4.2/include -std=c++11
LXXFLAGS = -LSFML-2.4.2/lib -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-network-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d -std=c++11

main.exe: main.o bishop.o king.o knight.o pawn.o position.o queen.o rook.o gui.o piece.o board.o Bishop.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 main.o bishop.o king.o knight.o pawn.o position.o queen.o rook.o gui.o piece.o -o main $(LXXFLAGS)


main.o: main.cpp GUI.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 main.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

bishop.o: Bishop.cpp Bishop.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Bishop.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS)

king.o: King.cpp King.hpp Rook.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 King.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

pawn.o: Pawn.cpp Pawn.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Pawn.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

position.o: Position.cpp Position.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Position.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

queen.o: Queen.cpp Queen.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Queen.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

rook.o: Rook.cpp Rook.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Rook.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

knight.o: Knight.cpp Knight.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Knight.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

gui.o: GUI.cpp GUI.hpp Queen.hpp Rook.hpp Bishop.hpp Knight.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 GUI.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

piece.o: Piece.cpp Piece.hpp Board.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Piece.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

board.o: Board.cpp Board.hpp Pawn.hpp Rook.hpp Knight.hpp Queen.hpp King.hpp
    g++ -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -std=c++11 Board.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: You don't seem to include `board.o` when building the .exe

Comment: Why do you repeat `-std=c++11` twice on every line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `board.o` when compiling `main.exe`